# Lightning earbuds

Tags: iphone

Apple just revealed iPhone 7 which comes with earbuds with lightning connector. Will these earbuds work with other iPhones with lightning connector such as iPhone 6/6s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  According to [Apple's product site](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMX62AM/A/lightning-to-35-mm-headphone-jack-adapter) for the lightning adapter:

> **Overview**
>   This adapter lets you connect devices that use a 3.5 mm audio plug to your Lightning devices.
>   **What’s in the Box**
>   Lightning to 3.5 mm Headphone Jack Adapter
>   **System Requirements**
>   Works with all devices that have a Lightning connector and support iOS 10 or later, including iPod touch, iPad, and iPhone.

Compatibility:

[image: Compatibility listing]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. several high end headphones already use the lightning connector rather than the 3.5 mm headphone jack.  http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/136466-best-lightning-headphones-2016-phones-for-iphones